In C# async/await, does delay length affect when control go back to the caller?
The following code works as expected - both services start at the same time.
List<Service> services = [ new Service(), new Service() ];

foreach (Service service in services)
{
    Task task = service.StartAsync();
}

Console.ReadLine();

class Service
{
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\tStarted");

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        //Simulate some synchronous work.
        Thread.Sleep(10_000);

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\tFinished");
    }
}

Output is:
20:32:25     Started
20:32:25     Started
20:32:35     Finished
20:32:35     Finished

But when you change the delay from TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) to TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(1), the output is:
20:40:10     Started
20:40:20     Finished
20:40:20     Started
20:40:30     Finished

Why does changing the delay affect behavior? Is there a race condition going on?

await Task.Delay may return immediately if the interval is short enough. If all awaited tasks are already complete, then the caller thread will block. You can force a task to move to the thread pool with Task.Yield or Task.Run. In other words, service.StartAsync will only return an incomplete task, when it awaits an incomplete task.

See the source code for Task: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs - your thousandth of a millisecond rounds down to 0, and else if (millisecondsDelay == 0)             {                 // return a Task created as already-RanToCompletion                 return Task.CompletedTask; applies; no waiting is done, the call is effectively a no-op. Change the threadsleep to an await delay if you truly want to synthesize some awaitable long running op (which is what you'd really be doing if you were putting it in an async)

(The answer to your question is "yes" by the way; the delay length does affect whether control returns)

Never ever mix Task and Thread

@MarioVernari Please suggest the alternative code to Simulate some synchronous work

@SirRufo I mean the OP has some intensive computation, hence I'd use some long loop or similar. What else would you use? you cannot rely on a thread, because you don't know what's going on behind the scenes.

@MarioVernari In this special case //Simulate some synchronous work I choose Thread.Sleep and no long loop or whatever. Do not get me wrong: I am talking only about this special case. Any other case is not part of my comment.


But when you change the delay from TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) to TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(1)...

The .NET timers don't have the ability to be triggered in sub-millisecond timespans. Any timespan smaller than one millisecond is evaporated to zero:
Task task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(999));
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(task, Task.CompletedTask)); // True

Online demo.
So the await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(1)); becomes await Task.CompletedTask;, which is a no-op. The execution flow continues synchronously. No scheduling takes place.
The await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync is also synchronous, because the Console.Out doesn't override the default implementations of the asynchronous TextWriter APIs, that are all implemented synchronously. The documentation of the Console.Out doesn't say this, but the documentation of the Console.In does:

Read operations on the standard input stream execute synchronously. That is, they block until the specified read operation has completed. This is true even if an asynchronous method, such as ReadLineAsync, is called on the TextReader object returned by the In property.

You can also verify it experimentally:
Task task = Console.Out.WriteLineAsync();
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(task, Task.CompletedTask)); // True

The result is that your StartAsync method becomes completely synchronous. Apart from its name and signature, there is nothing asynchronous in it. Everything inside it runs synchronously on the current thread. If you want to ensure that the execution of the services will be parallelized, you can use the Task.Run like this:
foreach (Service service in services)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => service.StartAsync());
}

This works because the Task.Run offloads the invocation of the function delegate to the ThreadPool.

In case you don't have control on how the StartAsync is called, you can convert the StartAsync to a facade that just calls a private StartAsyncCore method, offloading the call to the ThreadPool:
public Task StartAsync() => Task.Run(() => StartAsyncCore());

private async Task StartAsyncCore()
{
    // Implementation, that can be completely synchronous.
}

Exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods is inadvisable in general, but in this case you have no other option.


"If you want to ensure that the execution of the services will be parallelized, you can use the Task.Run". In my actual code, I cannot modify how services get called - think BackgroundService in ASP.NET. I need to ensure parallel execution. Would you agree with @JeremyLakeman that Task.Yield() from within a service will ensure parallel execution?


@Sandy no, I strongly advise everyone to use each tool for its intended purpose, and the intended purpose of the Task.Yield is not to facilitate offloading to the ThreadPool. The correct tool to use for this purpose is the Task.Run. It exists solely for this reason, and unlike the Task.Yield it functions always consistently regardless of the ambient environment. If you can't offload the StartAsync as whole, offload whatever part you have access to.

@Sandy I updated the answer with an example regarding your scenario.

Thank you for the detailed answer. One more questions. What would be the difference between public Task StartAsync() => Task.Run(() => StartAsyncCore()); and public Task StartAsync() => Task.Run(async () => await StartAsyncCore());

@Sandy there is no difference. Functionally it's exactly the same. In this case eliding async/await is harmless and also visually simpler. You can look at this question for more details.
